# Not getting updated updated from firestore while fetching with query

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

hey guys I have created a helper function to get all file whole role is customer in the profiles collection.

```
export const getAllCustomers = async () => {
  const q = query(collection(db, "profiles",), where("roles",  "==", "customer"), limit(5));

  try {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    const result = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      result.push(doc.data());
    });
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I am calling this function using tanstack react query in the component where I am rendering the data.
This is function, I am calling at the component.

```
  const {data, isLoading, error } = useQuery({
    queryKey:'latestCustomer', 
    queryFn: async ()=> await getAllCustomers(),
    staleTime:60
  });
```

I do get the data, but not the updated one. I have a profile in a firestore whose role I changed it to the admin, but I that profile still showing I get the data. When I try to check the data in the firestore its fine over there. The same issue I was having before when I was logging in the customer so one guy said to try to put "await" before the function where you are calling and it works fine. The same thing I tried here but no success.